# find and replace after the second column

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have the following lines

```
92520536843;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_am;EMAIL;28/01/2015;1;0;0;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_am;30/01/2015;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_Relance_am
92515196529;Sof_trav_Fort_Email_pm_%yyyy%mm%dd%;EMAIL;05/02/2015;1;0;0;Sof_trav_Fort_Email_pm_%yyyy%mm%dd%;09/02/2015;Export Trav_Fort Postal
```

I'm trying to replace strings like `Sof_` or `_%yyyy%mm%dd%` after the 7th **field**.

I thought about using `sed`

```
sed -i 's/<string_to_look_for>/<string_to_replace>/7g' filename
```

But it is only changing the field delimiter.

I thought about using this

```
awk -F";" '{ for (i=7; i<=NF; i++) print $i }' filename
```

but I don't know how to insert a search and replace for the strings I want to replace.

Any help is welcomed.

**edit : expected outcome after replacing strings like `Sof_` or `_%yyyy%mm%dd%` after the 7th column.**

```
92520536843;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_am;EMAIL;28/01/2015;1;0;0;voya_Faible_Email_am;30/01/2015;voya_Faible_Email_Relance_am
92515196529;Sof_trav_Fort_Email_pm_%yyyy%mm%dd%;EMAIL;05/02/2015;1;0;0;trav_Fort_Email_pm;09/02/2015;Export Trav_Fort Postal
```

to **Python and Perl** gurus, as i'm trying to ramp up my knowledge in these languages, your helps are welcomed:)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava : there you go

Comment: @AndyK why `Sof_` in the second example not getting replaced?

Comment: @AvinashRaj my bad. amended.

Comment: @AndyK what about perl?

Comment: @AvinashRaj : I'm learning python. Perl seems great but if you have an answer with Python, I would go for it instead of Perl. But if you have only perl, please shoot. I'm always willing to learn new things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/Sof_|_%yyyy%mm%dd%/, "", $i) } 1' file
92520536843;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_am;EMAIL;28/01/2015;1;0;0;voya_Faible_Email_am;30/01/2015;voya_Faible_Email_Relance_am
92515196529;Sof_trav_Fort_Email_pm_%yyyy%mm%dd%;EMAIL;05/02/2015;1;0;0;trav_Fort_Email_pm;09/02/2015;Export Trav_Fort Postal
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the while line from the input file, and note: this starts with field #7.  Your data exists earlier in each line.

```
awk -F";" '{ for (i=7; i<=NF; i++) 
   {gsub(/Sof_/,"newstring", ($i) } ; 
    print $0} ' filename
```

will replace Sof_ with "newstring".  I'm not positive this is what you are looking for.

Correct syntax error - removed erratn ' character - thanks

Comment: indeed that is what I want. Let me have a look.

Comment: First is this one `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: After amending the script to this `awk -F";" '{ for (i=7; i<=NF; i++) {$(i)=gsub(/Sof_/,"newstring", ($i) } }; print $0 ' filename` When running it, I have this error `awk: cmd. line:1:                                                             ^ syntax error`

Comment: Thanks - sorry about the typo.

Comment: Just tested it, made one change. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Through python3.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
fil = sys.argv[1]
with open(fil) as f:
    for line in f:
        part1 = ';'.join(line.split(';')[:7])
        part2 = ';'.join(line.split(';')[7:]).replace('Sof_','').replace('_%yyyy%mm%dd%', '')
        print(part1+';'+part2, end="")
```

save the above text in a file say `script.py` and then run it by,

```
python3 script.py inputfile
```

Through Perl.

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(?:[^;]*;){7}(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:_%yyyy%mm%dd%|Sof_)//g' file
92520536843;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_am;EMAIL;28/01/2015;1;0;0;voya_Faible_Email_am;30/01/2015;voya_Faible_Email_Relance_am
92515196529;Sof_trav_Fort_Email_pm_%yyyy%mm%dd%;EMAIL;05/02/2015;1;0;0;trav_Fort_Email_pm;09/02/2015;Export Trav_Fort Postal
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python you would use the re and csv modules to do this:

```
import re
import csv

with open(fn) as fin:
    r=csv.reader(fin, delimiter=';')
    for line in r:
        result=line[:7]
        for field in line[:7]:
            if re.search(r'Sof_', field):
                field=re.sub(r'Sof_', 'repalcaement for Sof_', field)
            if re.search(r'_%yyyy%mm%dd%', field):
                field=re.sub(r'Sof_', 'repalcaement for _%yyyy%mm%dd%', field)
            result.append(field)   
        print result
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^(([^;]*;){7}.*)(Sof_|_%yyyy%mm%dd%)/\1/;ta' file
```

This stores the first seven fields and following strings (that do not match the required strings) in the first backreference, then replaces the required strings by the said backreference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using perl's [`-F -a` and autosplit](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches):

```
perl -F";" -anE 'for ( @F[7..$#F] ) { $_ =~ s/Sof_|_%yyyy%mm%dd%//g } 
          print join ";", @F;' file.txt
```

This grabs elements 7 to last (`$#F`) of the autocreated `@F` array and removes/substitutes the text.